# Equations in ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is this possible ? And would it slow down the server with a query on a table with around 10,000 entries ?

My query is currently

```
SELECT title, number1, number2 ORDER BY number1
```

i would like to do something like this

```
SELECT title, number1, number2 ORDER BY (number1 + (number2 *100))
```

Comment: Did you have tested ?

Comment: what is you ID structure for parent and child?

Comment: Does `number1` ever have a value of 100 or more?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT title, number1, number2, (number1 + (number2 *100)) as OrderCondition  
ORDER BY OrderCondition
```

If you don't want a performance hit cache the result and add index to it.

Answer (score 0):

You create a fourth column in your table like "myindex".
In this column you put the result of your equation.
(This can be done either in PHP or with a trigger on INSERT.)
Then you just select order by myindex. This should be more efficient.

Comment: The equation can change over time. I need to do it in the SQL query.

Comment: Ok, then use the solution suggested by rokburgar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do it, you can use an alias as suggested by rokburgar or just include `(number1 + (number2 *100))`, however this computation must be also included in the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT title, number1, number2, (number1 + (number2 *100)) ORDER BY (number1 + (number2 *100))
```

For reference you can also have a look here: [MySQL sort on a calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369624/mysql-sort-on-a-calculation)

Answer (score 0):

In general, when using databases, the overhead for reading and writing data is much, much more than the overhead for calculations.  To do a sort, using filesort, the data must be read and written multiple times.  This will take much longer than the additional calculation.

So, in the case where the query uses filesort, the answer is that the calculation in the `order by` is negligible in terms of overhead.

On the other hand, if you are comparing to something like:

```
select title, number1, number2
from t
order by number1
```

*AND* you have an index on `number1`, then this will directly use the index, bypassing filesort.  In this case, the calculation in the `order by` results in a different execution plan that is more costly.

If the expression `(number1 + (number2 *100))` is a data element that you really care about, you might consider storing it directly in the database and building an index on it, perhaps using a trigger to keep it updated.

If you know that `number` is always between 0 and 99, then you will get better performance by doing:

```
order by number2, number1
```

and having an index on `(number2, number1)`.