# How to ORDER BY using psudo column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query

```
$query = SELECT * FROM 'tablename';
```

I take the query and put it through a while loop

```
$id = $row['id'];
$player = $row['player'];
$club = $row['club'];
$games = $row['games'];
$goals = $row['goals'];
$points = $row['points'];

if($points == 2){$cooef = "2";}
elseif($points == 1){$cooef = "1.5";}

    $pointsf = $games == 0 ? 0 : ($cooef*$goals);

        $showesm .= "
        <div style='$style' class='position'>" . $count . "</div>
        <div style='$style' class='recordplayer'>" . $player . "</div>
        <div style='$style' class='playerclub'>" .  $club . "</div>
        <div style='$style' class='position'>" . $games . "</div>
        <div style='$style' class='position'>" . $goals . "</div>
        <div style='$style' class='position'>" . $pointsf . "pts</div>
            ";
}
```

I want the resulting output to be ordered by the `$pointsf` column. Is this possible in php or MYSQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL sort on a calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369624/mysql-sort-on-a-calculation)

Comment: what is the value of $cooef if points is not equal to 1 or 2?

Comment: To mimic your original code which would have used 0 (as not defined, and thrown a warning) you'd need to add an extra `IF()` to your query - see my answer below.

Comment: $cooef will always be either 1 or 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate pointsf in your query and order by that:

```
$query = "SELECT *, IF(games=0,0,IF(points = 2, 2*goals, 1.5*goals)) AS pointsf
          FROM 'tablename' ORDER BY pointsf"
```

Comment: What about when points is not 2 and not 1.5? The old code would have used 0 (and thrown a warning).

Comment: I realized that after posting the answer, now asking @Aasim Azam what should be the behaviour

Comment: those are the only two numbers, there are no others, in both the database and in the multiplications, meaning there will never be a zero

Comment: ok, then this should work fine. But it is always better to cover every case even though they look impossible. Thanks to @LukeCousins for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Certainly :-) Use:

```
$query = SELECT * FROM 'tablename' ORDER BY IF(games = 0, 0, goals * IF(points = 2, 2, IF(points = 1, 1.5, 0)));
```

Presumably $cooef is 0 when $points is not 1 or 2